# Obtain administrators rights on Windows 7 when there is no administrator account

Tags: windows-7, administrator, active-directory, privileges

I've recently obtain a Windows 7 laptop.

It is managed via active-directory and I normally login using my ad username / password.

For personal uses, I'd like to obtain Administrator privileges. My ad account doesn't have them currently.

I've looked into `chntpw` (version 0.95 and 0.96). It shows three local accounts, and none of them has admin rights.
Activating them and clearing their password seems to work, but I can't give them admin privileges (`chntpw` quits with an error message when I try).

As far as I know, there is no local `Administrator` on the system (`chntpw` doesn't show them).

How can I create a new account that has Administator privileges ?

Comment: @DavidPostill Haha, they aren't nice :D

Comment: So, basically, you are asking how to get administrator privileges on a computer where you don't already have them. You show no evidence of being authorized to have these privileges, and you suggest that the owner of the computer doesn't want you to have privileges. You should post a selfie, so we can see what color your hat is. :)

Comment: If it's a company owned machine then you out of luck or out of a job if you succeed and they find out ... :/

Comment: [Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal) "Use of the Network or Services to violate the security of any computer network, crack passwords or security encryption codes, transfer or store illegal material including that are deemed threatening or obscene, or engage in any kind of illegal activity is expressly prohibited."

Comment: @DavidPostill This doesn't belong to any of theses categories afaik.

Comment: @blue112 Gaining unauthorized access to a computer system, including gaining access beyond your authority, is a crime in many jurisdictions. **For example,** in the US, [18 USC 1030 a 2 C](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1030#a_2) would *appear* to apply. If anything goes wrong when you are using the computer in excess of your authority, 18 USC 1030 a 5 A-C would certainly appear to apply. Caveat: I am not a lawyer, and certainly not in the US.

Comment: "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks" are strictly [off topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). This problem is entirely between you and your IT department. If they are not willing to give you local administrator rights then take it up with your manager.

Comment: There is no way to get Administrator permissions if this is an Active Domain account local Administrator permissions are basically useless on the domain itself

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in Administrator account (which can never be deleted, only disabled or renamed).

1. Logon with an account that already has Administrative privileges.  Your AD account is fine as long as you have local admin rights.
2. Start an elevated Command Prompt
3. Enable the local Administrator account by running **net user administrator /active:yes**
4. Specify a password with the command **net use administrator *yourpassword***

You can also complete these tasks by via the *Local Users and Groups* MMC Snap-In.  It can be started by typing **lusrmgr.msc** into *Search programs and files* on the Start Menu.

Comment: "Logon with an account that already has Administrative privileges" > I don't have one, *that's the point*

Comment: Very helpful to know. I see in your question you said you wished to "obtain" administrator privileges but you may wish to make your intent more explicit by clarifying that your AD account doesn't have admin rights.