# password administrator in windows 7

Tags: security

I am in guest user and I don't have any privilege , I don't have even access to a DVD writer and I can't boot system from USB or DVD , I don't access to BIOS . please help me I want to get administrator user or bring up my privilege . thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Obtain administrators rights on Windows 7 when there is no administrator account](http://superuser.com/questions/808196/obtain-administrators-rights-on-windows-7-when-there-is-no-administrator-account)

Answer (score 6):

Ask someone with these privileges to grant you the rights.

Or better said: This is impossible. If anyone would be able to get more rights on their own, what is the point in having user rights in the first place?

You need a user account with administrative privileges to grant user rights.